# Returning data from Redis only works the second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I'm using a Redis db and express routing for an api. Using node.js and ioredis too.

I connect to Redis and then go get all the keys related to the date entered and then get all the data related to each of those keys.

But what's strange to me is the it all works, but only on the second refresh of a page that requests it. So on first load of a page (say blah.com/api/20120120) it will return an empty array. Then if you refresh the page it'll return the correct data.

HomeController.js:

```
var theData = [];

function getData (date) {
    redis.on('ready', function (res) {
        var keys = [];
        var stream = redis.scanStream(
            {
                match: date + '*',
                count: 1000
            }
        );
        stream.on('data', function (resultKeys) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
                keys.push(resultKeys[i]);
            }
        });
        stream.on('end', function () {
            setValues(keys);
        });
    });
    return theData;
}

var setValues = function(keys) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        redis.hgetall(keys[i], function (err, result) {
            theData.push(result);
        })
    }
}

var HomeController = Controller.extend({

    api: function (date) {
        this.setRender();
        this.getResponse().json(getData(date));
    }

});
```

Server.js:

```
app.get("/api/:date", router("HomeController", "api", ["date"]));
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Edit: Added controller.js:

```
(function(module) {

    "use strict";

    // https://github.com/darlanalves/extends
    var extend = require("extends");

    var Class = function() {};

    var Controller = extend(Class, {

        constructor: function(req, resp) {
            this._request = req;
            this._response = resp;
            this._view = null;
            this._viewProperties = {};
            this._render = true;

            this.assign("loggedIn", false);
            this.assign("location", req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
        },

        assign: function(key, value) {
            this._viewProperties[key] = value;
            return this;
        },

        assignObject: function(obj) {
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.assign(key, obj[key]);
                }
            }
        },

        failWith404: function() {
            this.getRequest().log({status:404}, "controller 404");
            this.getResponse().status(404).render('404.jade');
        },

        getRequest: function() {
            return this._request;
        },

        getResponse: function() {
            return this._response;
        },

        getView: function() {
            return this._view;
        },

        getViewProperties: function() {
            return this._viewProperties;
        },

        render: function() {
            var viewProps = this.getViewProperties(),
                logProps = {
                    loggedIn: viewProps.loggedIn,
                };

            if (this._render !== true) {
                // No rendering, no headers
            } else if (this.getView() !== null) {
                // Jade
                this.getResponse().render(this.getView(), this.getViewProperties());
            } else {
                // JSON response
                this.getResponse().json(this.getViewProperties());
            }

            this.getRequest().log(logProps, "controller hit");
        },

        setRender: function(renderEnabled) {
            this._render = (renderEnabled === true);
        },

        setView: function(viewName) {
            this._view = viewName;
        }

    });

    module.exports = Controller;

})(module);
```

Comment: Whi9ch server framework is this? What is your `router` extending down there?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with this being async.

I also suspect that on each subsequent request, you would get the data that you requested in your previous one. Also if you have multiple users, they might get other people's requests.

Key problem: your `theData` is out of the scope of `getData` function.
Another keyProblem - you resolve this synchronously.

Simplified your code:

```
var theData = [];
function getData (date) {
    redis.on('ready', handler);
    return theData;
}
```

So, first call algorithm:

1. Set `theData` to []
2. Set some `handler` to wait for `redis` **ready** event.
3. Return `theData` (which is []);
4. Later on (when redis is ready) your handler sets `theData` to the results.

Second call:

1. you do not set theData - only the first time your module is loaded.
   Meaning, theData was what you last set it to (which is the data from the previous request, set by `handler`.
2. Schedule again the `handler` to do something on **ready** event.
3. Return `theData` (now holding the data from previous call).
4. Handler will later set the data to the new data.

Etc etc.

Basically, async problem.

*Edit: after your example code update:*

So with your code update, you'd have to do something like this:

The getData function should be async (return a Promise or use a callback). And your HomeController.

Example:

```
let HomeController = Controller.extend({

    api: function (date) {
        this.setRender();
        getData(date)  // Get data asynchroonously here
        .then(function(data) {
          this.getResponse().json(data);
         })
         .catch(function(err) {
           // handle error
           this.getResponse().status(500).json({message: 'Error getting data');
         });
    }    
});
```

But now there's a problem - `getData` needs to return a Promise.

```
let Promise = require('bluebird'); //unless you have Node 0.12+, it has Promise already.
function getData(date) {


  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   let theData = []; // initialize empty data for each req
    redis.on('ready', function() {

      var keys = [];
        var stream = redis.scanStream({
                match: date + '*',
                count: 1000
            });
        stream.on('data', function (resultKeys) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
                keys.push(resultKeys[i]);
            }
        });
        stream.on('end', function () {
            resolve(setValues(keys)); // Here we `resolve` our promise
        });
        stream.on('error', reject); // just a minor thing
    }
  });
}
```

But now your `setValues` also needs to be async, again with a Promise:

```
function setValues(keys) {

  // Return a promise to the initial caller.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    let parallelizedQueries = keys.map(function(key) {

      // Now, EACH of the hgetall also needs to be a Promise or somehow async
      return new Promise(function(innerResolve, innerReject) {

        redis.hgetall(key, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return innerReject(err);
          }
          innerResolve(result);
        });
      });
    });

    // So now we have asked for each of the keys, in parallel.
    // Wait until all of them succeed or fail on the first one.
    Promise.all(parallelizedQueries)

    .then(function(data) {

      // Here is our data.
      return resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

That should get you started, hopefully you can work from here.

Comment: Right - I figured it was something like this. I'm reasonably new to js, and very new to node/routing etc. Thank you for the detailed explanation, it makes sense now. How would I go about resolving this? ioredis includes bluebird (promises) but I cannot figure out how to use them correctly, do promises have something to do with it?

Comment: Well that's why I've asked what are you extending HomeController with. The `this.getResponse().json(getData(date))` - this part seems synchronous, do you have something like `this.getAsyncResponse()`?

Comment: Hey - I actually didn't write the controller.js unfortunately. Someone that I can no longer contact wrote it. I have edited my original post to show it